# Explain Noun + へ particle?

Tags: particles, verbs, nouns

I have a sentence:

> 来年にはテレフォニカが製品投入へ。

This is translated by Google:

> Telefonica is to rollout next year.

Where is the verb in this sentence as 製品投入 looks like "noun" + "noun"? And what is へ doing after the 投入.

I know that in Chinese 投入 can be both verb and noun, but japanese dictionary says it's a noun only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without additional context, this sounds like a newspaper headline or something similar.  In which case, the `へ` would act as "to" or "toward", implying the direction the Telefonica company will take in their business.  Something like

> "Telefonica to head toward product investment next year"

Again, if it's a headline or something, the verb is omitted yet implied.  Probably something like `向かう` <strike>or `移動する`</strike> would be appropriate; although if it were the latter, the `する` would also likely be omitted

> 来年にはテレフォニカが製品投入へ（向かう） or
>   <strike>来年にはテレフォニカが製品投入へ（移動（する））</strike>

Comment: thanks, but where is the verb here? What I have is:
来年に(Adverb) + は(Particle) + テレフォニカ(Noun) + が(Particle) + 製品(Noun) + 投入(Noun) + へ(Particle).
Do you mean that it is 投入 + へ that can be translated as "head toward"?

Comment: yes, it is a headline. I see now. Very interesting

Comment: Headlines should be translated to headlines. English headlines are also written in a peculiar dialect which is not always grammatical. Fragments appear instead of complete sentences and articles may be dropped.  Here is a possible translation to an English headline "Telefonica on to product investment next year".

Comment: Elision of a verb (and other kinds of elision) is grammatical in Japanese even outside of headlines. In a conversation, we can end up with a sentence ending in へ。 For instance:
どこへ行くの？　Where are you going?
東京へ(行くよ）。　(I am going to) Tokyo.
Particles like へ and から can take　の, by the way.
この電車は、東京への電車ですか？ Lit: This train, is it a heading-for-Tokyo train?

Comment: 移動(する) means actual movement from one place to another, and it cannot be used in this case.  向かう is fine.

Comment: @Kaz: It is true that elision is not specific to headlines, but the particular use of へ in the question (the one which means that it is a plan) is specific to headlines.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto:  What about just `移る` by itself?

Comment: @istrasci: I think that 移る is still unnatural in this case.  移る would be suitable if the company stops or completes something and starts something else instead.  In the present case, the company just starts something, so there is no “place” which they move _from_.